# Adding minutes the short hand of a clock

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, vector

I have a two dimensional vector `hour_vector` that represents the small hand of a clock.

For example, `[0, 1]` represents "12:00", `[1, 0]` represents "3:00". Similarly, `[1, 1]` shows "1:30" and so does `[2,2]` and `[10,10]` i.e. vectors of different lengths which are pointing to the same direction represent the same time.

I want to write a function that adds a number of minutes (`add_minutes`) to the time shown by `hour_vector` and returns a string `new_time` in the format "hh:mm".

```py
import numpy as np

# Finding the angle between the x-axis and a vector on the unit circle
def angle(hour_vector):
    if type(hour_vector) in [list, tuple] and len(hour_vector) == 2:
        b = [1,0]
        if hour_vector[1] >= 0:
            return round(np.degrees(np.arccos(np.dot(hour_vector, b)/ (np.linalg.norm(hour_vector) * np.linalg.norm(b)))), 2)
        else:
            return 180 + round(np.degrees(np.arccos(np.dot(hour_vector, b)/ (np.linalg.norm(hour_vector) * np.linalg.norm(b)))), 2)
    else:
        return ("The input needs to be a vector of length 2!")

# The main function:
def weird_clock(hour_vector, add_minutes):
    
    hour = 0
    minutes = 0
    add_minutes = 0
    remaining_minutes = 0
    new_time = ""
    
        # sections of a clock represented by angles on a unit vector
        # i.e. the angle between 60 and 90 is the section of a clock where
        # the hour is 12
    if 60<angle(hour_vector)<=90:
        hour = hour + 12
        minutes = minutes + (90-angle(hour_vector)) + add_minutes

    elif 30<angle(hour_vector)<=60:
        hour = hour + 1
        minutes = minutes + (60-angle(hour_vector))

    elif 0<angle(hour_vector)<=30:
        hour = hour + 2
        minutes = minutes + (30-angle(hour_vector))

    elif angle(hour_vector)>330 or angle(hour_vector) == 0:
        hour = hour + 3
        minutes = minutes + (360-angle(hour_vector))

    elif 300<angle(hour_vector)<=330:
        hour = hour + 4
        minutes = minutes + (330-angle(hour_vector))

    elif 270<angle(hour_vector)<=300:
        hour = hour + 5
        minutes = minutes + (300-angle(hour_vector))

    elif 240<angle(hour_vector)<=270:
        hour = hour + 6
        minutes = minutes + (270-angle(hour_vector))

    elif 210<angle(hour_vector)<=240:
        hour = hour + 7
        minutes = minutes + (240-angle(hour_vector))

    elif 180<angle(hour_vector)<=210:
        hour = hour + 8
        minutes = minutes + (210-angle(hour_vector))

    elif 150<angle(hour_vector)<=180:
        hour = hour + 9
        minutes = minutes + (180-angle(hour_vector))

    elif 120<angle(hour_vector)<=150:
        hour = hour + 10
        minutes = minutes + (150-angle(hour_vector))

    elif 90<angle(hour_vector)<=120:
        hour = hour + 11
        minutes = minutes + (120-angle(hour_vector))
        
    if minutes >= 60:
        hour += 1
        remaining_minutes = 60-minutes
        minutes = remaining_minutes
        new_time = new_time + (str(hour) + ":" + str(minutes))
        return new_time 
    else:
        new_time = new_time + (str(hour) + ":" + str(minutes))
        return new_time
```

However I'm not getting the desired output:

```py
weird_clock([1,0],15)
'4:-300.0' #Not the desired output
```

Comment: You are missing a closing paren at the end of `new_time + (str(hour) + ":" + str(minutes)` two places.

Comment: `new_time = new_time + (str(hour) + ":" + str(minutes)`: Parentheses don't match.

Comment: Fixed this, but still not getting the desired output from the function. Any ideas what I did wrong here?

Comment: Hard to say, when you printed stuff at different places in your program was there any obvious places that things were going wrong? You haven't explained how your code is trying to implement your algorithm so it might be hard for us to help. If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like setting breakpoints and examining values.  Also, printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening.

Comment: @wwii Will make sure to add comments now

Comment: In weird_clock you set `add_minutes` to zero.  The `add_minutes` passed to the function is ignored.  Remove `add_minutes = 0`, it works for 15 minutes.

Comment: When you tested the function `angle` with known inputs did it behave correctly? Can it be ruled out?

Comment: @wwii the angle function works without any issues

Comment: For `weird_clock([1,0],15)` what does `angle` return? With that return value, which conditional expression is True? In that conditional expression's suite are the hour and and minute offsets correct? When you test the function`weird_clock` for different angles do some of the conditional expressions work and some don't? Is there a pattern?

Comment: `angle([1,0])` returns `90.0`. Then, the conditional expression `if 60<angle(hour_vector)<=90:` is True. There doesn't seem to be a pattern between answers for different angles

Comment: When I call `angle([1,0])` it returns `0.0`

Answer (score 2):

`return` is not a function. Replace line 74 with:

```
return new_time
```

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/

Comment: Thank you, edited!  Appears that I missed a comma in that line of code which was another issue. I'm still getting the wrong output however